# Adobe Flash global security settings not taking effect

Tags: security, flash, adobe, global

I have a program that results in a security sandbox error. If I add the files to the trusted section of the global security panel. It works great on one machine but not another. I have all the settings the same as I can tell.

EDIT: I found something odd, on computers it works on the trusted files in Adobe Global Security Settings panel start with "///#/" where # is a number. On computers where it doesn't work the files start with C:.

Comment: So both machines have same settings? Both are same OS version, same privileges (_eg:_ are Admin accounts), no firewall preventing local SWF communicating with internet, etc etc?. You got it working on one so you're not doing it wrong, only leaves the other machine as problem...

Comment: I did more testing and got it to work on another computer but not the one I need it on. It seems that it works great on computers running Windows 7 Enterprise but not running Windows 7 Pro. What could be causing this? I've tried turning the firewall off, trying different browsers, installing updates, installing old versions of flash, and other things.

Comment: @VC.One The program takes a picture from the webcam and emails it to the user if that makes a difference. The upload script is hosted on an external server.

Comment: Is it `c:/xxxx` or `c:\xxxx` that isn't working (ie: forward or backslash for C drive)? For my _"Trusted File or Folder Location"_ is `e:\vc1` so dunno how you got forward slashes `///x/`... Wait are you doing this thru the [**settings website**](https://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html)? or from Window's Control Panel? I use Win's C.Panel to specify the hard drive folder where swf is located.